# insert entities to sql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, apache

I have an Entity Employee with fields and methods and I would like to have a method to add it directly to database(not through the typing it).However, when I run the program nothing is inserted in the database. Is there's a way to insert values into database like that?

```
  public void insert(Employee person) {
    Connection connection = null;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Employee5 (name,department)" +
                "VALUES (?,?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, person.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, person.getDepartment());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("INSERT INTO Employee5 (name,department)" +
                "VALUES (?,? )");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A) Check for errors. B) Step through your code to make sure it's actually executing. C) Check you're connecting to the same database you're looking for results in.

Comment: You probably need a transaction